# htaccess to make external images as thumbnail like API

Tags: .htaccess

how to make thumbnail based on remote image like this using htaccess?
http://api.thumb.com/http://factor45.org/images/beach.jpg

the result is it will show remote images, not store the images in my server

Thank you